# Can there be two certificates with a same serial number in the world?

Tags: cryptography, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, rsa, x.509

Recently I came across this odd question. I hope, Serial number is unique across certificates signed by a particular CA. So is there any chance that two different CAs sign two different certificates with same serial number?

Comment: The answer to the following gives you your answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-number-and-thumbprint

Comment: So, No CA in this world creates a certificate with already used serial number right? How CAs makes sure that a serial number is not used? And Does this apply to Internal CAs as well?

Comment: Did you actually read the accepted answer? Quote: 'A CA is supposed to choose unique serial numbers, that is, unique for the CA. You cannot count on a serial number being unique worldwide'